# Quarterly Date in a Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is structured as such

Date Value Variable

However, the date in my data is quarterly, read in from a .csv in the form 2000 Q1, etc. 
As such, my normal method of converting dates:

```
   mychart11$Date <- as.Date(mychart$Date , "%d/%m/%y")
   mychart11[order(mychart$Date),]
```

does not work because there is no %q option for quarterly.

I'm aware I could create quarterly dates from the data using the zoo package, but I need them to be in the dataframe, because I need to plot the dates using ggplot later using code like

```
geom_line(data=mychart, aes(Date, value, group="Date", colour="Total"), 
position=position_dodge(1)) + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"))
```

and because the date is a factor, I get the error message

> Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use the zoo package on dataframes.

Comment: zoo has direct support for ggplot2.  See `library(zoo); ?autoplot`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zoo` to convert your data to class `yearqtr` and then use `as.Date()` (from the zoo package...it is actually `as.Date.yearqtr()`) to convert to a regular date.

```
mychart11$Date <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(mychar$Date),frac=0)
```

Notice that `frac=0` will create a resulting date that is at the beginning of said quarter.  Use `frac=1` to get the end of the quarter.  In between values are also permitted, though I can't think they would be common.